# ¿Cómo mostrar una variable de una consulta en ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Quiero mostrar en mi variable profesor datos en el value el id del profesor, y en entre las etiquetas  Nombre y apellido  Les dejo capture de mi consola y mi código. 
-> var profesor='  ';

Lo que hay en mi Consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código java script:

```
$(function() {
$( '#select_profesor' ).on('change',onprofesorchange);

});

function  onprofesorchange () {

var id= $(this).val();
  $.get('/api/asignar-profesor/'+id+'/profesor', function(datos)  {
console.log(datos);

 var profesor='<span  class="btn btn-success btn-xs" value="">  </span>';

$('#div1').html(profesor);

});
```

Comment: Si es un solo dato: **`var profesor='<span  class="btn btn-success btn-xs" value="' + datos.id +'">'+datos.nombre + ' ' + datos.apellido +  '</span>';`** Si son varios tendrías que leerlos dentro de un bucle.

Comment: Solucione el problema de esta manera   ` var profesor='<span draggable="true" id="drag1"  ondragstart="drag(event)"     class="btn btn-success btn-xs" value="'+datos['0'].id+'">  <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" >    '+datos['0'].nombre+' '+datos['0'].apellido+'  </span>';`

Comment: Ciertamente, porque los datos venían en un array. También lo puedes hacer con un bucle... sobre todo cuando son varios datos, ya que así sólo te mostrará el primer registro, aunque me extraña que te funcione con el `cero` entre comillas: `datos['0']` ¿?

Comment: 0 porque es la primera posicion del array 1 es la segunda posicion y a si sucesivamente, en la posicion 0 se guardaron todos los datos de la consulta de este id

Comment: Lo sé, pero suele ser así: `datos[0]`, lo que me extraña es que funciones con el `'0'` entre comillas.

Answer (score 0):

Como la respuesta es un array solo tendrias que acceder al indice 0 y luego las propiedades id y apellido:

```
$(function() {
    $('#select_profesor' ).on('change',onprofesorchange);
});

function  onprofesorchange () {
    var id= $(this).val();
    $.get('/api/asignar-profesor/'+id+'/profesor', function(datos)  {
        console.log(datos);

        // accedemos al indice 0 y lo mostramos
        var profesor='<span  class="btn btn-success btn-xs" value="'+datos[0].id+'">' + datos[0].nombre + ' ' + datos[0].apellido +' </span>';
        $('#div1').html(profesor);
    });
}
```